# Firebase Debugview not showing data for the event on web console

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

we have configured Firebase correctly and it's working fine up-to yesterday morning.

But event data (attributes and values ) are not showing for the events but it's showing event name and time .

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

I don't have any idea about why it's happening.

is it configuration side issue ? or Firebase debug view issue?

Thanks

Comment: Same here. Firebase issue. Tap to events in "TOP EVENTS" and you will see parameters.

Comment: thank you , but it's not showing items array for the event view_item

Comment: Then you need to setup BigQuery streaming export to see events in intra day table. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue happening on firebase analytics debugview. And issue fixed without changing app and firebase configuration